# How to get floating point number by passing its hexadecimal equivalent (IEEE format) in Perl?

Tags: perl, ieee-754

I know that 10.51200 is saved in memory as 0x4025065220000000 using IEEE floating point format. But when i pass this to sprintf() function in Perl like below i am getting wrong value as output. Can you please suggest where i am going wrong.

$temp = 0x4025065220000000;

$temp1 = sprintf("float: %f \n",$temp);

print "$temp1";

**Output:**

float: 4622107541822767104.000000

Comment: I can reproduce it, and get a warning with `use warnings` on 5.24.1 on 64bit Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: My guess is that Perl thinks it's an integer. A very BIG integer. `perl -MO=Concise -e 'printf("float: %f \n",0x4025065220000000)'`

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, `0x4025065220000000` is 10.51235, not 10.51200 - that would be `0x40250624dd2f1aa0`. Anyway, see [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html):

```
$ perl -wMstrict -le 'print unpack("d>",pack("q>",0x4025065220000000))'
Hexadecimal number > 0xffffffff non-portable at -e line 1.
10.5123453140259
$ perl -wMstrict -le 'print unpack("H*",pack("d>",10.51200))'
40250624dd2f1aa0
$ perl -wMstrict -le 'print unpack("d>",pack("q>",0x40250624dd2f1aa0))'
Hexadecimal number > 0xffffffff non-portable at -e line 1.
10.512
```

Note that your Perl has to be compiled with support for quads for the above (see the output of `perl -V`). If you don't like the warning, you can use strings instead:

```
$ perl -wMstrict -le 'print unpack("d>",pack("H*","4025065220000000"))'
10.5123453140259
$ perl -wMstrict -le 'print unpack("d>",pack("H*","40250624dd2f1aa0"))'
10.512
```

Comment: Presumably the number isn't hardcoded, but comes from somewhere, in which case they won't get the warning. It's only for hardcoded numbers. The warning can also be silenced.